# Not displaying output in JS number game

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements

I'm a student and I'm doing an assignment for my coding class which involves me making a random number game that asks the user for input and then display the output. So far my code looks like this. We just started conditionals and I'm unsure about a couple of things.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Random Number Game</title>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Guess a random number!</h1>
        <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Type guess here!"><br>
        <button onclick="displayOutput()">Submit</button>
        <p>Type in a number 1 - 100 in the space above and see if you were right or not.</p>
        <span id="output"></span>
    </div>

    <script>

        function displayOutput() {
            let inputValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
            let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1, 101);

            if (inputValue == null || inputValue == "") {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 
                    "You have to enter a value between 1 and 100";
            } else if (inputValue != randomNumber) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 
                    "Your guess was incorrect. Try again.";
            } else (inputValue == randomNumber) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 
                    "You guessed correctly! Your number was " + inputValue "Good job.";
            }

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I put a number in and was obviously, expecting it to display and it didn't. I thought maybe I got some names wrong or messed up in the conditionals. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: `Math.random() * 1` is the same thing as `Math.random()`; you end up with a value between 0 and 1. I think you mean `Math.random() * 100 + 1`

Comment: Also open your browser console and check for errors. That should be step 1 whenever you're having problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were small issues in your code.

1. First of all you added `</style>` that isn't making any sense. I simply removed that.
2. `else` statement cannot have a condition if you want to add more conditions you should use `else if (condition)` but `else` is the last one with no condition.

Here, is your code with little changes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Random Number Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Guess a random number!</h1>
        <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Type guess here!"><br>
        <button onclick="displayOutput()">Submit</button>
        <p>Type in a number 1 - 100 in the space above and see if you were right or not.</p>
        <span id="output"></span>
    </div>

    <script>

        function displayOutput() {
            let inputValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
            let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() *1,101);

            if (inputValue == null || inputValue == "") {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 
                    "You have to enter a value between 1 and 100";
            } else if (inputValue != randomNumber) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 
                    "Your guess was incorrect. Try again.";
            } else{
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 
                    "You guessed correctly! Your number was " + inputValue+ "Good job.";
            }

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```